# Save data permanently in database

Tags: c#

Guys I have a problem in saving data in my database.
 The system I am developing saves data in the database and displays the data in the datagrid and that runs smoothly, but the problem is whenever I restart or reboot the application the data disappears and the database was again empty but the data entered directly in the database using show table data, didn't disappear.
Am I missing something in my program?

Comment: I bet you are using a local database, aren't you?

Comment: If you are using an explicit transaction, make sure you commit it. If you aren't check that your servers autocommit mode is set to true.

Comment: ..are you loading the data in? Or just updating the datagrid with the new record once it's entered? Sounds to me like you're persisting the data but not loading it when your application starts..

Comment: @eman welcome to Stack Overflow, you'd better talk here if you want your problem solved. People are trying to help you, so you should talk to them.

Comment: A bit more context would be helpful: **what** database? What kind of application (web? Winforms? WPF? Silverlight?) You should read Jon Skeet's [How to ask a **good** question on SO](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints) (or at least his [short version of it](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist.aspx) ) and embrace those tips!

Comment: @MahdiTahsildari i'm using service-based database windows form.

Comment: @eman what is your database? SqlServer? or local Sql (like somename.sdf)

Comment: @MahdiTahsildari it shows database.mdf

Comment: @SimonWhitehead i am inserting the data in a new row and the data was saved smoothly but then if i exit the application and execute it again, the data i entered in my last execution disappears.

Answer (score 4):

Do the following steps:

1. Right click on your Database.mdf or Database.accdb database file from solution explorer
2. Click on properties
3. Select 'Do Not Copy' from COPY TO OUTPUT DIRECTORY drop down list
4. Remember to close your database if it was opened on access

Comment: If you could've just mentioned the option "Copy if newer" that would've saved me from 3 hours of research... If "Do not Copy" option don't work for you try "Copy if newer"...!!!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem long time ago. I remember that the data that I would enter in a execution would vanish on the next execution and it was because the local database file was copied (and hence overwritten) on each execution.

I solved it by setting `Copy to Output Directory` property of my local database to **Do not copy** I suppose, test it, if it's not **Do not Copy** then it may be **Copy Always**.

But I'm sure my (same) problem solved this way.
Hope it works in your case too.

**EDIT**:
Eman, do the following steps. It should solve your problem.

1.right click on your abc.mdf database file from solution explorer
2.hit properties
3.change COPY TO OUTPUT DIRECTORY
4.run your application, add a row, exit app, run it again
5.if row is lost, goto step 1, else exit

Comment: ye i used that method in Web Form, but when I use it in Windows form, errors occur.

Comment: i'm sorry sir but i can't. Its too expensive to call you.

Comment: uhmm, actually were not. but can you still help me?

Comment: @yes of course. You know I'm 99% sure why you are losing data, it's because whenever you run your app a fresh copy of your database.mdf file gets copied over the old one. You just need to switch the `Copy to Output Directory` option to find the appropriate case.

Comment: when i set Copy to output Directory to "Do Not Copy", this error occur An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\NIAR6MIS\NIAR6MIS\bin\Debug\MainDatabase.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.

Comment: @MahdiTahsildari hey man I think you just saved my entire day. I had the same problem, and will not do what you've said. Up voted.

Answer (score -1):

try using sql server database.
write the code in form_load().