# Cannot insert data into database using procedure

Tags: c#, database

I'm trying to insert class object into local database in Visual Studio.

This is the code of procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sp_InsertBike

@Brand varchar(50),
@Model varchar(50),
@EngineVolume int,
@Year int

AS

INSERT INTO Bikes(Brand,Model,EngineVolume,Year)
VALUES (@Brand,@Model,@EngineVolume,@Year)

SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

Class:

```
class Bike
{
    public String brand { get;set;}
    public String model {get; set;}
    public int engineVolume {get;set;}
    public int year {get;set;}
}
```

and insert code:

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(LINQ.Properties.Settings.Default.Database1ConnectionString);

try{
    connection.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_InsertBike", connection);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Brand", "Suzuki");
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Model", "GS500");
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EngineVolume", 200   );
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Year", 2005);

    cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    connection.Close();
}
catch
{
    connection.Close();
}
```

After that, there's no record in my database. Can you tell me wha I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try ExecuteNonQuery() instead of ExecuteScalar()?

Comment: Yes, I did. Without any effect..

Comment: In this case, You can open Sql Server Query profiler and capture the query sent to the database. Then try to execute it directly on the database to find the error. You can also try to remove try{}catch{} to let the application break on error.

Comment: Try calling the proc with dbo.sp_InsertBike. If that doesn't work, try actually catching an exception with catch Exception(e) rather than just 'catch', and see if one is being thrown

Comment: I was debuggin it, and it doesn't go into "catch". It looks like it does everything fine, but just doesn't insert :/

Comment: Can you manually run the proc in SSMS?

Comment: Are you sure your connection string is set up properly in web.config and you are running the procedure against the database you think you are?

Comment: Does your table have a Primary Key?  And is that Primary Key an identity column in SQL Server?

Comment: Also, closing the connection (like you are) is not correct. Use the 'finally' block. Check if its not null / not closed, then close it.

Comment: That's a bad way to handle exceptions

Comment: Ok, it's started to work. Don't know what helped. But now, when I run the program again, added rows disapears. Is there a saving option or something?

Comment: Found the answer here :[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14313480/save-data-permanently-in-database)
Thanks for your time!